# Activity class does not exist android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-launcher

I am trying to debug my application and upon clicking the button i get the Activity Class {} does not exist error which reads like so: "Error: Activity class {sprint.telematics.sprinttelematicstracking/track.my.world.LoginActivity} does not exist."

The problem is not with the "track.my.world" package name as this does exist but the section before the forward slash:"sprint.telematics.sprinttelematicstracking" as there is no longer anything in the application named this.

I have transferred my project from Eclipse to Android Studio and also changed the package name from "sprint.telematics.sprinttelematicstracking" to "track.my.world" and this is when the error started to occur. My android manifest file contains the correct package as shown.

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="track.my.world"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/trackmyworldicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity 
        android:name="track.my.world.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

How would i be able to change where android studio is looking to launch the app from as i think it is looking in the wrong area for the LoginActivity

Thanks

My build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "track.my.world"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
             manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
             java.srcDirs = ['srcc']
             resources.srcDirs = ['srcc']
             aidl.srcDirs = ['srcc']
             renderscript.srcDirs = ['srcc']
             res.srcDirs = ['res']
             assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm i think you should move to https://www.eclipse.org/

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any imports in any of your class files for sprint.telematics.sprinttelematicstracking ? Also check none of your class files have `package sprint.telematics.sprinttelematicstracking` in them.

Comment: . I started work on a Windows PC using Eclipse before switching to a Mac with Android Studio on it. Didnt think it would have caused much of an issue?

Comment: I would make yourself sure that all of your classes are titled with the correct package name.

Comment: I have used a search to find anything by the name of sprint and found nothing out of the ordinary. All layout files use the correct context and all classes use the "track.my.world" package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you migrate your project to gradle?

In that case look at the build.gradle file for the packageName. Gradle will override the package name in the androidManifest.xml during the build of the app.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        packageName "com.your.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: in build.gradle i dont have a defualtConfig i do have sourceSets though?

Comment: This did change what i was looking for however it did not fix my problem. I created a new app and moved the classes, resources and libraries over which fixed the problem. Must be an error within the build files, as suggested, which i cannot find a solution to

Comment: Ive added it to my question above userM143372

Answer (score 0):

Take a look through some of the build files for the Eclipse project. It appears to have gotten confused and you can just do a "find" function in the main build file and you will probably find "sprint.telematics.sprinttelematicstracking" and then just get rid of it or change the line accordingly.

Comment: I will have a look through the files again but i cant seem to see anything that stands out as wrong. Very annoying

Comment: Hm ok, be sure to let me know